# How can I limit my printf statement to 80 characters per line in the code in c++?

Tags: c++, printf

My professor requests that my code does not exceed 80 characters per line, but I have some printf statements that exceed this limit. Is there a way to break this statement into two or more lines without changing the output?

Example by request:

```
printf("\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d%-20s %-4d\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n", "1 - Ones", ones, "2 - Twos", twos, "3 - Threes", threes, "4 - Fours", fours, "5 - Fives", fives, "6 - Sixes", sixes, "7 - Three of a Kind", threeOfAKind, "8 - Four of a Kind", fourOfAKind, "9 - Full House", fullHouse, "10 - Small Straight", smallStraight, "11 - Large Straight", largeStraight, "12 - Yahtzee", yahtzee, "13 - Chance", chance, "Total Score: ", score);
```

Comment: When asking a question like this, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Oh, and you should totally hand in your assignment on a deck of [80-column punched cards](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Punched_card). After all, that's where all this "maximum 80 columns" stuff originated from.

Comment: @GregHewgill I had to dig up this question so I could tell you that here I am, in 2017, facing an issue with an ABAP program dump because my program lines are longer than 72 characters. [Sometimes I hate SAP](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/661589).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, you can break literal strings like this:

```
printf("This is a very long line. It has two sentences.\n");
```

into

```
printf("This is a very long line. "
       "It has two sentences.\n");
```

Any double-quoted strings that are separated by only whitespace, are coalesced into one string by the compiler before parsing. The resulting string does not contain any extra characters except what is between each pair of double quotes (so, no embedded newline).

For the example included in your post, I might do the following:

```
printf("\n%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n"
       "%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d%-20s %-4d\n"
       "%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n"
       "%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n"
       "%-20s %-4d %-20s %-4d\n",
       "1 - Ones", ones, "2 - Twos", twos, "3 - Threes", threes,
       "4 - Fours", fours, "5 - Fives", fives, "6 - Sixes", sixes,
       "7 - Three of a Kind", threeOfAKind,
           "8 - Four of a Kind", fourOfAKind,
           "9 - Full House", fullHouse,
       "10 - Small Straight", smallStraight,
           "11 - Large Straight", largeStraight,
           "12 - Yahtzee", yahtzee,
       "13 - Chance", chance, "Total Score: ", score);
```

Comment: How about some ginormostatement like the one I edited into my original post?